# kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init exitcode 0x00000100

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, updates

I was running Ubuntu 20.02 on my Dell Inspiron i5-5559. Some days back, I was notified with the latest updates available, and today i decided to update. I tried to update and upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 and I was thrown with this error while boot:

end kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode 0x00000100

I even tried to boot with my earlier kernel versions from the grub menu, but i was encountered with the same error. The error comes in recovery mode too. I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please help!

Comment: Sorry, actually the error occurred after I performed upgrade followed by an update. How to remove the mentioned error? It stays like that for hours and hours and won't go any further than that.